# Why is the Network Layer processing of a packet happening in kernel space rather than on the NIC?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, kernel

As in the title I am wondering why demultiplexing the IP headers of an incoming packet is happening in kernel space.
Wouldn't it easier to do it on the NIC together with the Link Layer processing?

The assumtion is that no TCP offload engine is active.

Comment: Usually the same reason crypto is done on the cpu rather than a dedicated coprocessor - it is faster and cheaper. A 3 GHz cpu can outperform an inexpensive 50 or 100 MHz coprocessor on the NIC. Most modern processors also have instructions to accelerate CRC-32 checksums, too. CRC acceleration includes Intel SSE4.2, ARMv8, PowerPC and POWER8. In fact they can use Polynomial Multiplies like PCLMULQDQ, PMULL and VMULL combined with Barret reductions to achieve 0.25 cycles-per-byte checksumming.

Comment: @jww I largely agree with you except to say that the dedicated ASICs are actually faster and outperform the CPU...  Yes, it's cheaper to do it on the CPU, but it's usually slower, especially when you factor in the software processing that could be offloaded to the NIC.  That said, with the exception of checksum and TCP segment offloading with server class NICs, or custom ASICs designed for 100Gbe+ packet capture, we do not do this processing on the NIC, we do it in the kernel.

Comment: @David - Yeah, I forgot about custom implementations like ASICs. I usually only see the custom gear in high performance systems, like US Financial and trading platforms. Are they common for the commodity case? (Those high performance ASIC programming jobs usually pay well, too. I've seen salaries of 200K USD).

Comment: IP, a layer-3 protocol, is independent of the layer-2 protocol, and the layer-2 protocol can carry any number of layer-3 protocols. For example, IP can be carried by ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, FDDI, ATM, frame relay, etc., and ethernet can carry IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc. Tying the hardware with the layer-3 protocol would have required all new hardware to upgrade from IPv4 to IPv6, but the separation in layers means that your NIC can use both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: there are many offload options available on a NIC. try `ethtool -k eth0` you'll find options for vlan, ipv4, ipv6, tcp sctp esp, ... of course it all depends on hardware and driver